Find $\pi_1(K\#\dots\#K\#\mathbb S ^ 2)$
Find $\pi_1(K\#\dots\#K\#\mathbb S ^ 2)$ where $\#$ is the connected sum of two topological surfaces and $K$ is the Klein bottle.
We induct on the number of Klein bottles considered in the connected sum. When there is but one bottle, we have that $K \# \mathbb S ^ 2 \simeq K$ so that $\pi_1(K \# \mathbb S^2)=\langle a, b : aba^{-1}b\rangle$.
In general, we follow Munkre's drawing for the CW-complex representation of the connected sum for the two tori, albeit we use the ordering of the edges in the Klein bottle (instead of the torus) and alternate the orientation of the edge upon which we are performing the attachment.
For $n=2$,

For $n=3$,

For a general $n$, the connected sum is taken in a like fashion, thereby finishing the induction.
I conclude that
$$\pi_1(K\#\dots\#K\#\mathbb S ^ 2)\cong\left\langle x_1,\dots,x_n:\prod_{i=1}^n x_{2i-1}x_{2i}x_{2i-1}^{-1}x_{2i}\right\rangle$$
If my answer is not correct, I would appreciate a comment telling me where I am mistaken.
Thank you

Sorry about that, I moved my hypothetical solution from the answers section to the question section.

I would say it looks like an essentially correct idea, though you could explain many more details (depending on what exactly is expected of you). In particular, some description of what you're drawing would be nice: you sort of glossed over that you've drawn the punctured klein bottles, and the fact that these can be drawn as pentagons instead of as squares-with-holes, and the fact that gluing together the pentagons is indeed the connected sum. (I'm not sure exactly what definition you use for connected sum--do you have some theorem about connected sums of cell structures for surfaces?).
Also, you didn't really use induction; you just said "in a like fashion", which can be turned into an inductive proof, but it isn't exactly one currently. Where should you use the inductive hypothesis?
An easier way to make everything rigorous in my opinion would be to use Van Kampen's theorem, and actually use induction.

I appreciate this feedback. When I read about using the connected sum, I just imagined cutting a loop out of the CW-complex and pasting another CW-complex along that loop. Is there a rigorous definition for a CW-complex? I guess I'm still trying to find the right degree of rigor in my proofs. Many of Hatcher's arguments appear to focus on the geometric intuition, but I guess in trying to emulate him, I fell short on ensuring that all of the facts were complete. I'll go back in my notes and use Van Kampen's theorem like I did to compute the fundamental group of the torus. Thanks

Your approach works, but it's a little bit hard to follow why exactly each step is a homeomorphism. Adding the pentagons/hexagons as intermediate steps do make things easier to read though. All of the spaces you are dealing with are quotient spaces of a disk, where the specified identifications define the equivalence relation that you quotient by. It is true that the gluing of two such spaces along some un-identified segment does result in a disk with the "concatenation" of the identifications, but you may want to mention this, depending on who your audience is.

Your definition of connected sum is good: it's the quotient (along the disk's boundary circle) of the union of the two surfaces after removing the interior of some disk from each. How many details you want to include really depend on if you want to make sure you understand the relevant point-set topology concepts like the quotient topology. In practice, after a first course in topology, a lot of algebraic topology proofs might leave out some of those point-set topology details, assuming they could be filled in by a reader if in doubt.

Currently, I'm taking my first course in topology. For one reason or another, our class goes through the first half of point set topology and then jumps to Hatcher 1.1 through 1.3. It certainly is a steep learning curve for a beginner. I appreciate all the time you took to assist me; I'll need all the help I can get if I'm going to have any hope on my final. Thanks again.
